# cURL SyntaxError: Unexpected token &#39; in JSON at position 0<br>

Tags: node.js, express, curl

When I execute this request `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:3000/messages -d '{"text":"Hi again, World"}'` on cURL to an express I get this error

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token &#39; in JSON at position 0<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\Atom\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\Atom\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Atom\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Atom\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\Atom\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Atom\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)</pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't know what I did wrong, since I'm just copy pasting stuff from [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api) tutorial. I did my search and cannot find any syntax error on the curl request, still that's what the error is about, I understand that the &#39 is the single quote ('). Any help will be highly appreciated. My app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
require('dotenv').config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let users = {
    1: {
        id: '1',
        username: 'Robin Wieruch',
    },
    2: {
        id: '2',
        username: 'Dave Davids',
    },
};

let messages = {
    1: {
        id: '1',
        text: 'Hello World',
        userId: '1',
    },
    2: {
        id: '2',
        text: 'By World',
        userId: '2',
    },
};


app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(Object.values(users));
});

app.get('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(users[req.params.userId]);
});

app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    const message = {
        id,
        text: req.body.text
    };

    messages[id] = message;

    return res.send(message);
});

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(Object.values(messages));
});

app.get('/messages/:messageId', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(messages[req.params.messageId]);
});


app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('POST HTTP method on user resource');
});

app.put('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(
        `PUT HTTP method on user/${req.params.userId} resource`,
    );
});

app.delete('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(
        `DELETE HTTP method on user/${req.params.userId} resource`,
    );
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

further investigation shows that if you are using a windows cmd terminal you may need to escape the double quotes and avoid single quotes, so for instance on git bash the following works

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"route": "Test route"}' http://192.168.1.xx:xxxx/
```

but not on windows cmd. For that I used:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"route\": \"Test route\"}" http://192.168.1.xx:xxxx/
```

Note change the xx xxxx to your own url, port

The source for this insight was
https://github.com/biofects/Google-Home-Messages/issues/3

Gordon

Comment: After days and days of investigation, finally, an answer that deserves all the attention but unfortunately no one said anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what terminal you used but I was having the same error when using node.js command prompt. The issue was fixed in my case by using bash terminal instead.